# Game Physics - Friction

Tags: java, physics

My very simple question is: how would I implement friction? Nothing I try seems to be working.

Oh, and `speedX` = 1.

Here's my code:

```
public void update() {
    x += velocityX;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        vx = xSpeed;

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        vx = -xSpeed;
}

public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        vx = 0;

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        vx = 0;
}
```

Edit:

Now, once the player stops, he slows down (which is good), but he doesn't stop completely.

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        vx = 0.20 * vx;

        if (vx < 0.2)
            vx = 0;

        playerAction = "still";
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a formula for friction or is figuring that out part of the assignment?

Comment: @ChetterHummin I don't, I'm a total newbie to game dev. :)

Comment: Are you even a newbie to simple physics ?

Comment: @noob, nice username :P Nope, I took physics in school. I know what friction is, the problem is implementing it into the code.

Comment: You could try having the speed be decremented by an amount until it is <= 0.

Comment: Do you want sliding friction or air resistance?

Comment: I don't know if you still need help with this but the problem with your edit code is that 0.20 * 1 = 0.20 which makes the vx < 0.2 never fire thus it never stops.

Answer (score 1):

Friction is a force opposite to velocity.  If you're dealing with forces at all, gravity or electric fields or rocket engines or something more mysterious, just add to the total force one more computed as velocity times some coefficient.  You could get fancy and make its magnitude proportional to the speed squared or cubed, for different effects. Then compute velocity and position as usual.

If you're not dealing with forces and F=ma, but using a simpler kind of physics based only on velocity, which is common in video games, you need to decrease that velocity gradually.   For each time step, compute  new_velocity = 0.99 * current_velocity.  Use whatever coefficient gives the right amount of slow-down.  Again, you could get fancy and involve velocity squared in some way to alter the feel of the object's slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

Often friction is assumed to be a constant force, considering the friction between two surfaces with a [constant normal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Dry_friction), which would slowdown your objects velocity linearly. Other frictional forces like air drag often also have linear and quadratic terms.
If you would want to use friction between two surfaces you could do it like this:

```
if (vx > 0) vx += -friction / mass;
if (vx < 0) vx +=  friction / mass;
```

I also included the mass to suffice `F = m * a` for the acceleration. If there are also other forces acting on the object it would be a little more complicated since if the object has stopped moving it would only start moving again if the remaining forces exceed the frictional force.

By the way if you would like to make it more numerical correct, you could add a time step size into the simulation: `vX += accelerationX * timeStep;` and `x += vX * timeStep;`.

Comment: Ok but hear me out, this would make vx do a bouncy thing around 0 whenever vx / (friction / mass) is not an integer

Answer (score 1):

I have worked as a game AI engineer.  That often involves making gameplay and physics.  I recently had to answer this question myself.  That's why I found this.  Here is my solution.  My problem may be a little different from yours but my challenge was to make it work no matter what framerate I was using.  Here's my solution:

```
speed -= (speed * (1 - friction)) / fps;
```

friction is always a float between 0 and 1, 1 being no friction and 0 being essentially infinite friction.  This makes sure the the right amount of friction will be applied proportional to frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

If `u`, `m` and `g` in `Ff=umg` for the formula for the force of surface friction is constant, then a in `F=ma` would also be a constant number. Also because `a = deltaV/s` that means that the velocity equals acceleration times time (`as=deltaV`). This means that for every time interval the `deltaV` remains the same if `Ff` is the same. The change in speed only stops if it is not moving(`v=0`). So I think the best way to do this is to detect whether it's moving or not and apply the constant `deltaV` (for the opposite direction) and not apply it when `v` reaches zero.

Answer (score -1):

Friction is a force that slows down any objects you have that are moving.  So you'd need to have something like a background thread that constantly  looks at the speed of all your objects, and slowly decrements each speed towards zero.

Comment: Thanks for the (super) fast response! I already tried something like this in the `update()` method. Instead, my character just flew off the screen. Could you provide an example? :3

Comment: I don't know what all your variables are or how your user inteface works.  However, if you've got two speed variables vx and vy for the speed in the x and y direction, then the background thread could do something like `vx *= 0.99; vy *= 0.99` to reduce both speeds by 1% at the same time.

Comment: thanks! Very helpful. Only problem is now, when the player stops, he slows down but doesn't stop completely. Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: do if (vx < minSpeed) vx = 0;

Comment: Decreasing by 1%, you never reach zero.  So as @Axis says, implement a minSpeed.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail. I edited my OP with more details :) Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: if (vx < 0.2)
            vx = 0; along with  vx = 0.20 * vx;  needs to go into your update method. It doesn't make sense to have them in a key event method.